# How can I use a factory inside a "resolve" of $stateProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

As title I want to use a factory insisde a "resolve"
app.js:

```
    angular
    .module("goHenry", ["ui.router"])
    .factory("httpPost", httpPost)
    .controller("MainCTRL", ["$scope", MainCTRL]);

function MainCTRL($scope, httpPost){
    this.nameApp = "CiaoMiao";
    console.log($scope.children, httpPost);
}

function httpPost($http, $q){
    return {
        get: function() {
             var deferred = $q.defer();
             $http.post.apply(null, arguments)
                       .success(deferred.resolve)
                       .error(deferred.resolve);
         return deferred.promise;
        }
    }//RETURN
}
```

routers.js:

```
    var httpConfig = {headers:{ "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }};

    var config = ["$urlRouterProvider", "$stateProvider", function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("multi",{
                url: "/multi",
                    "viewA@multi": {
                        templateUrl: "app/templates/login.htm",
                        controller: ["$scope", "getChildrenNumber", function($scope, getChildrenNumber){
                            this.nameApp = "nameAppChanged";
                            this.gatto = "Miao";
                        }],
                        controllerAs: "ctrl"
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    getChildrenNumber: ["$http", function($http, httpPost){
                        var httpP = httpPost.get("http://domain.com/user/login/api-login", $.param({ username:"ciaociao6@ciao.com", password:"ciaociA0" }), httpConfig)
                        console.log(httpP);
                        return "Some response from an API";
                    }]
                }
            });
angular
    .module("CiaoMiao")
    .config(config);
```

As result of console.log I got "undefined", I don't get how to inject that factory at this part of the code.
I tried to put into the main controller of that view, but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Could you please correct DI array to getChildrenNumber: ["$http","httpPost",  function($http, httpPost){

Comment: $http already returns a promise so it is redundant to also use `$q`. Also shouldn't need to inject $http in the resolve function. Is request being made? Check browser dev tools network

Comment: What you're saying is not true, I need to inject $http service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(If you place the resolve at your view it should work. 
If you need that resolve in multiple views of the same state. I would try to use an abstract state and add the resolve there.) Works but is not needed (see edit below.)

Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjd6zthz/) or the demo below.

I've reduced the demo a bit to keep things easier to read. Also not added array notation for DI in the demo. 
You don't need to use the deferred object in your factory because `$http` is already returning a promise.

**Edit:**
You can place the resolve outside of the view and it should work too. I've tried it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjd6zthz/1/).
So there's probably a different issue in your code.

OK, I think the problem with your code is that you're not returning the resolved value from your promise. Something like `promise.then(function(response) {return response;});`

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router'])
    .factory('myDataFactory', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function (id) {
            return $http.post('http://crossorigin.me/http://www.mocky.io/v2/55a65562b2016ce10c7e6ea9', {
                id: id
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        }
    };
})
    .config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/124');

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/:id',
        views: {
            'viewA': {
                template: '{{hello}}',
                controller: 'homeController',
                resolve: {
                    backendData: function (myDataFactory, $stateParams) {
                        return myDataFactory.get($stateParams.id);
                    }
                }
            },
            '@': {
                template: 'main view'
            }
        }

    });
})
    .controller('homeController', function ($scope, backendData) {
    console.log(backendData);
    $scope.hello = backendData;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ui-view=""></div>
    <div ui-view="viewA"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe because I've got separating files, but it seems like "myDataFactory" hasn't been called at all

Comment: I forgot to put  <myDataFactory> inside < backendData: function() >

Answer (score 3):

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router'])

.factory('AbcService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('app/rest/abc', {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true}        
    });
})
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('abc', {
            templateUrl: "scripts/abc.html",
            url: "^/abc",
            controller: 'abcController',
            resolve: {
                resolvedData: ['AbcService', function(AbcService) {
                    return AbcService.query();
                }]
            }
        })
    })
.controller('abcController', function ($scope, resolvedData) {    
    $scope.data = resolvedData;
});
```