# Unable to inject my service in Angular resolve inside router configuration

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-services

(My plunkr code resides at http://plnkr.co/edit/6KU3GblQtMdRAx3v3USV?p=preview)

I'm trying to create a Search bar (in navigation) which should ultimately hit the backend REST API. The input search button when clicked on input 'alpha' would trigger a route to products/search/0?searchtext=alpha

Clicking on the button triggers a route change, which should do resolve as follows:

```
.when("/products/search/:page", {
        templateUrl: "products.html",
        controller: "ProductsSearchController",
        resolve: {
            // Define all the dependencies here
            ProdSearchServ : "ProdSearchService",
            // Now define the resolve function
            resultData : function(ProdSearchServ) {
                return ProdSearchServ.searchProducts();
            }
        }
    })
```

However, I'm getting the following error

> angular.js:9784 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ProdSearchServProvider <- ProdSearchServ

I believe I'm doing most of the things as per conventions, may be I'm missing something here?

I'm copying **script.js** code below (also in plnkr link above). It has all the route configuration and the controllers defined.

```
(function(){


// jargoViewer Create a new Angular Module 
// This would go into the html tag for index.html
var app = angular.module("jargoViewer", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/main", {
            templateUrl: "main.html",
            controller: "NavController"
        })
        .when("/products/search/:page", {
            templateUrl: "products.html",
            controller: "ProductsSearchController",
            resolve: {
                // Define all the dependencies here
                ProdSearchServ : "ProdSearchService",
                // Now define the resolve function
                resultData : function(ProdSearchServ) {
                    return ProdSearchServ.searchProducts();
                }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:"/main"});
});

}());

// Nav Controller
(function() {
var app = angular.module("jargoViewer");

var NavController = function($scope, $location) {
    // Function to invoke the Prod search based on input 
    $scope.search = function() {
        console.log("searchText : " + $scope.searchtext);
        $location.path("products/search/0").search({searchtext: $scope.searchtext});
    };
};

app.controller("NavController", NavController);

}());

// Define the Prod Search Service here
(function() {
// Get reference to the app
var app = angular.module("jargoViewer");

// Create the factory
app.factory('ProdSearchService', function($routeParams, $http, $q) {

    var searchProducts = function() {
        pageNum = 0;
        searchParam = '';
        if (('page' in $routeParams) && (typeof $routeParams.page === 'number')) {
            pageNum = $routeParams.page;
        } 
        // Check if the router Param contains the field searchtext, if so, check if its a string
        if (('searchtext' in $routeParams) && (typeof $routeParams.searchtext === 'string')) {
            searchParam = $scope.routeParam.searchtext;
        }

        // Now make the http API hit to fetch the products
        var request = $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "http://abcd.com/products/search/" + pageNum,
            params: {
                search: searchParam
            },
         });
        return(request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    };

    function handleError(response) {
        // The API response from the server should be returned in a
        // nomralized format. However, if the request was not handled by the
        // server (or what not handles properly - ex. server error), then we
        // may have to normalize it on our end, as best we can.
        if (
            ! angular.isObject(response.data) ||
            ! response.data.message
            ) {
            return($q.reject( "An unknown error occurred."));
        }
        // Otherwise, use expected error message.
        return($q.reject(response.data.message));
    }

    // I transform the successful response, unwrapping the application data
    // from the API response payload.
    function handleSuccess(response) {
        if(response.data.error == true) {
           return($q.reject(response.data.message));
        }
        return(response.data.data);
    }

    return {
        searchProducts : searchProducts
    };
});
}());

// Define the Products Search Controller below
(function() {

var app = angular.module("jargoViewer");

//var ProductController = function($scope) {
var ProductsSearchController = function($scope, $routeParams, ProdSearchService) {
  // Nothing to do really here
};

app.controller("ProductsSearchController", ProductsSearchController);

}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This caused by your bizarre naming conventions.  Sometimes `ProdSearchServ` and sometimes `ProdSearchService`.

If you just pick one and use it consistantly then you won't run into these types of errors.

[Fixed Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UqmUQHTGQjObvXBiwpqz?p=preview)

In particular you create the service with the name `ProdSearchService` and then attempt to use it with a different name:

```
app.factory('ProdSearchService',
//vs
resultData : function(ProdSearchServ) {
```

I imagine you we under the impression that this code would fix it for you.  However, this only applies to dependencies passed into the controller, not functions in general.  For services which already exist, you do not need to define them specially like this; instead simply use the correct name in the controller.

```
// Define all the dependencies here
ProdSearchServ : "ProdSearchService",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to define the dependency when you say

```
// Define all the dependencies here
ProdSearchServ : "ProdSearchService",
```

Just do this:

```
.when("/products/search/:page", {
        templateUrl: "products.html",
        controller: "ProductsSearchController",
        resolve: {
            resultData : function(ProdSearchService) { //as you defined it before
                return ProdSearchService.searchProducts();
            }
        }
    })
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430231/how-can-i-use-a-factory-inside-a-resolve-of-stateprovider)

Comment: Thanks ! I wish I could choose both the answers as accepted answer!

Comment: @Jamboree it's OK. When you [earn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you can [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all answers you consider useful to you ;)